# Which Function is used for Get the exact location of GPS Coordinates of DJI Drone for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dji-sdk

I want the GPS Coordinates of a DJI Drone in iOS. I need the method or property to get GPS location when Takeoff.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two options:

**1/ Delegation** on DJIFlightController aka [DJIFlightControllerDelegate Protocol](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html#djiflightcontroller_updatesystemstate_inline)

You will implement this method and get a [DJIFlightControllerState](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController_DJIFlightControllerCurrectState.html#djiflightcontroller_djiflightcontrollercurrectstate) object which will have a location:

```
- (void)flightController:(DJIFlightController *_Nonnull)fc didUpdateState:(DJIFlightControllerState *_Nonnull)state {

    CLLocation *myCurrentLocation = state.aircraftLocation;
    // Do something here.
}
```

**2/ Using the keyed interface** and this key [DJIFlightControllerParamAircraftLocation](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController_DJIFlightControllerCurrectState.html#djiflightcontroller_djiflightcontrollercurrectstate_aircraftlocation_inline) (see SDK Key note)
This key will send you a value which contains a CLLocation.

Then you could either do a simple get

```
guard let locationKey = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightControllerParamAircraftLocation) else {
     NSLog("Couldn't create the key")
     return
 }

 guard let keyManager = DJISDKManager.keyManager() else {
     print("Couldn't get the keyManager")
     // This will happen if not registered
     return
 }

 if let locationValue = keyManager.getValueFor(locationKey) {
     let location = locationValue.value as! CLLocation
     // do something
 }
```

or listen to all updates

```
guard let locationKey = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightControllerParamAircraftLocation) else {
      NSLog("Couldn't create the key")
      return
}

guard let keyManager = DJISDKManager.keyManager() else {
     print("Couldn't get the keyManager")
     // This will happen if not registered
     return
}

keyManager.startListeningForChanges(on: locationKey, withListener: self) { (oldValue, newValue) in
     if newValue != nil {
         let location = newValue!.value as! CLLocation
         // do something
     }
}
```

Just don't forget to stop listening when you're done.

I hope this helps.

PS: I've mixed Swift and Obj-C because you can use either.